# how to get user data from sql while listing notifications in php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Just like facebook, I have a website which shows lots of notifications from other users.

What I'm doing now is saving notifications of others if they are related to me with my user I'd and the actual user id of that notification in a table called notifications.

And when I login to dashboard I'm fetching all, for each notification I need to display user name so I'm making a query with each notification for the user using the id saved.

Its not efficient and a slow process when I get more notifications on dashboard.

I'm sure there is another tricky way..if I log into facebook it manages very quickly.

Any one had this situation? I'm sire every developer crossed this state, please help me if you have found any better ideas in solving this. So we query once for the associate user and bring the data in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance you could retrieve the username by using a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in your query when retrieving the notifications for a specific user e.g.

```sql
SELECT `message`, `username` 
FROM `notifications` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `notifications`.`from_user` = `users`.`id`
```